# Unity LoadScene did not seem to work properly

Tags: unity, c#, visual-studio

My logic is simple: after conditions are met, display an image (an `Image` class instance) and restart the stopwatch. After a certain time, reload the scene. In a `MonoBehaviour` script I wrote:

```
if(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds > sceneReloadTime)
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
}
```

`sceneReloadTime` time was set to `3000`, which should be 3 seconds, but after displaying the image for 3 seconds, the image remains there and the scene did not seem to have been reloaded.

Out of confusion I put a breakpoint and used Visual Studio's debug tool, and confirmed that it has indeed entered the `if` and seems to have gone through `LoadScene`. I hit `continue` in VS and was led to a seemingly reloaded scene, but very dark as if the exposure has been tuned down to near zero.

This "dark world", however, only appears when I use VS debug and hit continue. If I play in Unity it never seems to reload and will be stuck on the image forever.

What could have gone wrong? Thank you.

Comment: So you are reloading the scene without going to another scene? Why? (Not being snide, just trying to understand the use case.)

Comment: @AcmeNerdGames It's a scene that is largely random-generated, especially the map. The thought was to let the player play again.

Comment: So -- why not simply load a blank scene (or interstitial) before (re)loading the scene, or, reset stuff instead of reloading? My hunch is that you are wandering into an edge case that is not supported.

Comment: This is indeed a weird problem. My guess would be that something goes wrong during the loading and instantiation of the new scene which does not get properly catched and reported. Have you tried loading the scene with [LoadSceneAsync](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync.html)?

Comment: Or could it be possible that the value of `stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds` is scene-independent, so when the scene reloads it is still on the old value, which results in the scene getting reloaded in an infinite loop?

Comment: Is this code inside Update method, i.e. how you wait for the time to pass?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reloading the scene itself, load a small “helper” scene that then loads the main scene again. The helper scene could be a opportunity to present high scores etc.